# Segment Control: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I want to create an app including Segment Control and a label, change the label when the control is pressed.

I want to use "sender" to get the value of the segment control but why it's not working?

```
-(void)segmentControlIndexChanged:(id)sender
{
    switch ([sender selectedIndex]) {
        case 0:
            label.text = @"Case Zero :)";
            break;
        case 1:
            label.text = @"Happy New Year!";
            break;
        default:
            label.text = @"Press a button:";
            break;
    }
}
```

---

Other trouble:
the code below causes:

-[ViewController segmentControlIndexChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

```
//ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    IBOutlet UISegmentControl *segmentControl;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *label;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UISegmentControl *segmentControl;
```

-

```
//ViewController.m
-(IBAction)segmentControlIndexChanged
{
    switch ([segmentControl selectedSegmentIndex]) {
        case 0:
            label.text = @"X'mas always come first :)";
            break;
        case 1:
            label.text = @"Happy New Year!";
            break;
        default:
            label.text = @"Press a button:";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `sender` what you think it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because `UISegmentedControl` has `selectedSegmentIndex` property, not `selectedIndex`:

```
switch ([sender selectedSegmentIndex]) { // <<== Here
    case 0:
        label.text = @"Case Zero :)";
        break;
    case 1:
        label.text = @"Happy New Year!";
        break;
    default:
        label.text = @"Press a button:";
        break;
}
```

Sometimes, Xcode lets you pick a wrong method; when you are not certain of the exact name, consult [developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) available online and through Xcode's Help/Documentation and API Reference.

Comment: Just found it! haha, thanks, also, but I've the other trouble here: (Let see 1st thread)

Comment: -[ViewController segmentControlIndexChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Because `-segmentBlahBlah:` and `-segmentBlahBlah` are two different methods. One takes an argument; the other does not.

Comment: @PlusA This is because you removed `sender`. You cannot do that: the IB expects your code to take `sender` whether you use it or not, otherwise your method has a wrong signature, causing the error that you see. Just put the `:(id)sender` back, and it will work. I would also use `sender` in the switch, but that's my personal preference.